# —this was in the days before Spreckels had arisen—

Tags: meaning, proper-nouns

Does anybody know what the authors refer to by this hint? Adolph B. Spreckels seems to have been an industrial magnate in San Francisco. Among others he was obviously vize-president of the Oceanic Steamship Company. It seems to me this is what the authors refer to.

> My heart sank; perhaps my idiotic jest had indeed driven him away; and again I asked myself, “Why?” and whirled for a moment in a vortex of untenable hypotheses.
> “What was he like, ma'am?” Pinkerton was asking, when I returned to consciousness of my surroundings.
> “A clean-shaved man,” said the woman, and could be led or driven into no more significant description.
> “Pull up at the nearest drug-store,” said Pinkerton to the driver; and when there, the telephone was put in operation, and the message sped to the Pacific Mail Steamship Company's office **—this was in the days before Spreckels had arisen—** “When does the next China steamer touch at Honolulu?”
> “The City of Pekin; she cast off the dock to-day, at half-past one,” came the reply.
> “It's a clear case of bolt,” said Jim. “He's skipped, or my name's not Pinkerton. He's gone to head us off at Midway Island.”
> Somehow I was not so sure; there were elements in the case, not known to Pinkerton—the fears of the captain, for example—that inclined me otherwise; and the idea that I had terrified Mr. Dickson into flight, though resting on so slender a foundation, clung obstinately in my mind.

(From The Wrecker by R. L. Stevenson and L. Osbourne, chapter X, published 1892)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolph_B._Spreckels
https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Wrecker_(Stevenson)/Chapter_10

Comment: His father Claus Spreckels and brother John D. Spreckels seem to also have been industrialists involved in the shipping business.

Comment: It's obscure to the modern reader - This has no particular meaning to native speakers of English nowadays, so just skip over it. It doesn't seem to be important to the plot. Probably merely that after John Spreckles had "arisen", it would have been natural to phone the Oceanic Steamship Co. and this line just explains to the reader 100 years ago why the Pacific Mail was telephoned, and not the Oceanic.

Comment: @ James  K - "Probably merely that after John Spreckles had "arisen", it would have been natural to phone the Oceanic Steamship Co. and this line just explains to the reader 100 years ago why the Pacific Mail was telephoned, and not the Oceanic." - Yes, thank you, that was my question and I understand it in the same way.

Comment: Interesting use of **touch at**, BTW.  And *a clear case of **bolt*** is noteworthy.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question does not appear to be about learning the English language within the scope defined in the [help center](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an American speaker of modern English, I can tell that this is referencing something that is no longer common knowledge. Let's break down the phrase, and then take a look at the outdated reference.

### Asides

> "...the telephone was put in operation, and the message sped to the
> Pacific Mail Steamship Company's office —this was in the days before
> Spreckels had arisen—..."

This sentence is using dashes to indicate an **aside**, or a phrase giving related information but that isn't part of the main sentence. In modern written English, you might see an aside noted by dashes like this or you might see parentheses or commas. The aside usually gives more information about something that comes immediately before it.

19th and early 20th century writing used this writing structure a lot, and frequently told stories from the perspective of an older man telling a younger audience about events. Because of this, many works included asides explaining older technology, cultural touchpoints, etc., that in the rapidly changing world of the late 1800s and early 1900s, would not be familiar to "younger" audiences. Unfortunately, the explanations they gave are now not familiar to us either!

Because of where it's placed in the sentence, this aside could be giving more information about:

- The act of telephoning or the phrase "the message sped"
- the Pacific Mail Steamship Company
- the office

### Spreckels

> —this was in the days before Spreckels had arisen—

To figure out which of these things the aside is giving more information about, we need to figure out what Spreckels is. Some things we know:

- It's a proper noun, probably the name of a place, person, or company
- It's something that could "arise" meaning "come to prominence" or "become important." Sometimes this phrasing could also mean "started existing" or "was created." We also know there was a time before Spreckels. Because of that, we guess that it might be a person who gained political power or a company that was founded. Possibly it could be a place that wasn't politically important at first, but that seems less likely in context.
- We also know it must relate to either telephoning, the Pacific Mail Steamship Company, or the office that the characters are calling.

I think you got to most/all of this, because the next step is to start googling, which you did! You found Adolph B. Spreckels. Looking at his wiki article, we can find a link to Oceanic Shipping Company, by his son, John D. Spreckels. Some digging there looks like he worked in Hawai'i and would have directly competed with the Pacific Shipping Company or taken its place. It was founded in 1881, which would have been enough before this book was published that the author could have assumed everyone would know what it was, but reasonably before the events of the book were supposed to take place. That seems to match what we know.

So! We can then understand that this aside is giving us extra information. Specifically, it's telling the reader that the characters are calling the Pacific Shipping Company to ask when the next ship is arriving. And they are calling that specific company because the Oceanic Shipping Company, which contemporary readers would be more familiar with, didn't exist yet.

The author/narrator refers to the Oceanic Shipping Company by the name of Spreckels implies that the family name would have been more prominent than any individual business.